# AWS Elasticbeanstalk whitelist single IP for consuming external APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I have a Elasticbeanstalk cluster, currently with a single instance. My idea is to define a elastic scalability but first I need to be able to provide specific IPs to my providers to whitelist.

I researched about it, and the NAT gateway seemed to be the best choice.

So I created the NAT gateway following this guide [here](https://medium.com/@obezuk/how-to-use-elastic-beanstalk-with-an-ip-whitelisted-api-69a6f8b5f844) however, adding a rule in the Main Route Table to route 0.0.0.0/0 to my NAT gateway causes that all my instances are now not accessible by their public IPs.

Sounds like it would be possible to route specific public IPs to the NAT Gateway, but the APIs I have to consume are providing a DNS name and I can't use a DNS in the route table.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Doesn't sound like a strange scenario, so for sure there is a standard solution that I'm missing.

Thanks,

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything that indicates you can use a hostname in either a route table or a security group outbound ACL, but maybe it wouldn't be too hard to automate adding all the IPs that your hostname can resolve to with the aws cli or direct API calls.

Comment: @Derek I have postponed this task, but looks like the main issue is having the subnet I want to route through NAT as a public subnet. 
I'm going to make that subnet private and try again. Although I'm not sure the root cause of the issue, but I have seen in several posts that is the way to go.

Comment: Hi there, was this solved somehow? I have the same issue